# How to get the selected contacts from Check box (Android)

Tags: android, list, checkbox, view

I am creating a group android SMS. Therefore, i need checkbox. But,my problem is i cant figure out how to get the selected contacts?

This my layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/topLayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

<ListView 
 android:id="@+id/list" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice">
</ListView>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/contact_image"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Name: "
     android:id="@+id/contact_name"
     android:textSize="18dip"
     android:layout_below="@id/contact_image"      
        />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Phone: "
           android:id="@+id/phone_number"
            android:textSize="28dip"
            android:layout_below="@id/contact_name"  


         />
         <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"     android:focusable="false">
   </CheckBox>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

This my codes:-

```
  package com.droidnova.android.samples;

   import android.app.ListActivity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.provider.Contacts.People;
  import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
  import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.MenuInflater;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;



   public class Contacts extends ListActivity {
private CheckBox checkBox;
private ListView listView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById (R.id.list);
    final ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, lv_items));  





    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, 
            new String[]{People._ID,People.NAME,People.NUMBER}, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    // start mappings
    String[] columns = new String[] {People.NAME, People.NUMBER};
    int[] names = new int[] {R.id.contact_name, R.id.phone_number};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact,   cursor, columns, names);
    setListAdapter(myAdapter);
    this.setListAdapter(myAdapter);
}



     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.firstmenu,menu);
    return true;  
  }  
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
  switch(item.getItemId()){
  case R.id.next:
      next();
    break;
  case R.id.select:
     return true;
  case R.id.back:
      final Intent i = new Intent(this,SelectContact.class);
      startActivity(i);
      break;
  }
return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read contacts separately in array, then do whatever you want with that array.........

For sample, you can check over here, 
http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/

This will help you.........

Comment: I've did the array.But it seems that i face the same problem.

Comment: Create another array of type Boolean(ex: checkedArray) having same number of elements as  contacts, by default keep each false, then onListItemClick, make the element at that position in "checkedArray", as true or false, depending on the original state, ex: if it's true and onListItemClick is called again make it false, so at last the array will have all the check and unchecked elements....

Answer (score 0):

This my updated codes. Whenever, i click on the 'Mark' menu button, it doesnt get the selected item and display at Edit Text.

updated Codes:-

```
    package com.droidnova.android.samples;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.zip.Inflater;
   import android.app.ListActivity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.Contacts.People;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
    import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.MenuInflater;
 import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

 public class Contacts extends ListActivity {
ListView list;
CheckBox cb;


private static String[] PROJECTION = new String[]
{
    People._ID,
    People.NAME,
    People.NUMBER,
};

  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.contact);
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, 
            null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);


    // start mappings
    String[] columns = new String[] {People.NAME, People.NUMBER};
    int[] names = new int[] {R.id.contact_name, R.id.phone_number};

    ListAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.contact, cursor,columns,names);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

  }


 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.firstmenu,menu);
    return true;  
 }  
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
  switch(item.getItemId()){
  case R.id.mark:
    next();


    break;
  case R.id.select:



      return true;
  case R.id.back:
      final Intent i = new Intent(this,SelectContact.class);
      startActivity(i);
      return true;
  }
return false;
  }
    private void next() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

  SparseBooleanArray a = list.getCheckedItemPositions();

  for(int i = 0; i < PROJECTION.length ; i++) 

  {

  if (a.valueAt(i))

  {

  Long val = list.getAdapter().getItemId(a.keyAt(i));

  Log.v(TAG, "index=" + val.toString());

  list.add(list.getAdapter().getItemId((a.keyAt(i))));

  }

  }

}
```

}